# MarkLogic CORB - What're permissions to run corb

Tags: marklogic-corb

What're permissions allow developers to run corb for selecting/updating nodes in MarkLogic.

roles: hadoop-user-read 
       hadoop-user-write

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exact permissions will depend upon your environment.

At a minimum you will need to be able to login to the XDBC server and eval code and/or invoke modules, read URIs, and write documents.

I'd start by giving the user the **rest-evaluator** role, which will give them **rest-reader** and **rest-writer** roles, plus the following execute permissions:

- xdbc:eval
- xdbc:eval-in
- xdbc:invoke
- xdbc:invoke-in